# Can not trigger any javascript events inside popover in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I've been dealing with this issue for a couple of days and I just found out that I can't trigger any events inside a bootstrap popover. I even tried to trigger an `alert()` and it does nothing.

I have a popover with a button in it. When you click the button the text on it change. Any help? **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/whcya/1/)**. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Michael pointed out in his answer, the popover element does not exist in the HTML until the link is clicked. So the `click` handler can't attach to it until after the link is clicked.  So you can either move the click handler into the popover call, or use the jquery `on` delegate, like this:

```
$('.location').on('click','.text-btn',function () {
    alert('What\'s going on!');
    //$('.text-btn').toggle();
});
```

See this work in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whcya/7/)

What this does is the following:  It attaches a click handler to the element with the `location` class. When anything inside this element gets clicked (such as the `text-btn` element), the event bubbles up and triggers this handler.  However, the `on` handler listens only to events that are triggered by specific elements (in this case elements that have the `text-btn` class).  Since the the handler is attached to the `.location` element and this element is non-dynamic, it will always be available.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are assigning an event listen on a node that does not exist yet. If you look at the HTML that is generated when you click on `Fire popover` the following HTML is generated:

```
<div class="popover-content">
     <button class="btn text-btn">Toggle me!</button>
     <button class="btn text-btn toggle-text">Un-Tobble me</button>
</div>
```

The problem is that this was generated after your listener code ran on the document - therefore there is no listener on your button.

Hopefully someone else can tell you how to add the listener as I can't figure it out.