# Jquery what to load first

Tags: jquery

I have a index.html file that uses the JQuery below to load a page of menus into a div when the page is opened. The listeners in the code below work with any elements in my index.html file but they do not work with elements in the files that were loaded by the jquery script.

Here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { // this runs as soon as the page is ready (DOM is loaded)

    $("#leftmenu") // selecting "div" (you can also select the element by its id or class like in css )
       .load("http://www.maa.intranet.bae.co.uk/ma/Content/bus_serv/integrated_services/supply_chain_ss/information_assurance/leftmenu.html"); // load in the file specified

    $("#content").load("WebContent/welcome.html");

    $("div.menuitem").hover(
             function () {
               $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
             }, 
             function () {
               $(this).css({"background-color":"blue"});
             }
         );


    $(".menulink").click(function(){
        alert("This is a test");
    });

});
```

Comment: And what is your html? You probably want to use .on(), since the menuitems aren't loaded yet when the .hover() executes.

Comment: Take a look at the solution for the accepted answer. It is a similar situation to yours that may simply require you to update how you are handling events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663154/can-not-trigger-any-javascript-events-inside-popover-in-bootstrap/17663397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { // this runs as soon as the page is ready (DOM is loaded)

    $("#leftmenu") // selecting "div" (you can also select the element by its id or class like in css )
       .load("http://www.maa.intranet.bae.co.uk/ma/Content/bus_serv/integrated_services/supply_chain_ss/information_assurance/leftmenu.html"); // load in the file specified

    $("#content").load("WebContent/welcome.html");

   $("body").on('hover','div.menuitem',
             function () {
               $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
             }, 
             function () {
               $(this).css({"background-color":"blue"});
             }
         );


    $("body").on('click','.menulink',function(){
        alert("This is a test");
    });

});
```

explanation :

future element -- you cant attach them listeners

So you attach to a higher level ( "body" in this case) and then when clicks occur - the target is compared and invoked.

*p.s. im sure there are at least 5 duplicate questions.*

Answer (score 1):

Use the complete function, ref http://api.jquery.com/load/

That would be

```
$("#leftmenu")
  .load("http://www.maa.intranet.bae.co.uk/ma/Content/bus_serv/integrated_services/supply_chain_ss/information_assurance/leftmenu.html")
  .complete(function( // do event binding here ) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic content, use event delegation. Try converting some of your handler that targets newly loaded content to the following style syntax:

```
$(document).on("click", "#selectorName", function() {
    ^             ^
    ^              Selector action, could be hover, change, etc.
    ^
  This is the container for the newly loaded elements, drill down as far as you can to this, in this case, we'll just use document.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/on/

You use it like this:

```
$('ElementThatIsAlreadyThereAndWillStayThere')
.on('click','#elementyouwantToBindTheEventTo', function(){
    //Handle "click" event here.
});
```

You can also use other events like .on('hover', ...)